# Finding a counterexample to a claim about nonnegative polynomials

Tags: polynomials, examples-counterexamples, convex-geometry

A sketch of the proof of the following statement is in Barvinok's "A Course in Convexity".

> Fixing positive integers $k$ and $n$, define $H_{2k,n}$ to be the real vector space of all homogeneous polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $2k$ in $n$ real variables. Then, if $p\in H_{2k,n}$ is a positive polynomial, there exists a positive integer $s$ and vectors $c_1,\cdots,c_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $$\|x\|^{2s-2k}p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m\langle c_i,x\rangle^{2s} ~~ \mbox{for all} ~~ x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Here, given $c=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the notation $\langle c,x\rangle$ is used to denote the linear polynomial $\sum_i\lambda_ix_i\in H_{1,n}$.

Note that by 'homogeneous polynomial', we are simply referring to a polynomial in which the (nonzero) terms all have the same degree; and by 'positive polynomial', we are simply referring to a polynomial $p$ for which $p(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: why does this claim fail if "positive polynomial" is replaced with "non-negative" polynomial? I've tried to parse the proof to see where strict positivity is required, but the proof is dense. It seems like there should be a good counterexample. This is a homework question, so I appreciate hints.

**Edit:** I am able to show that the Motzkin polynomial ($p(x,y)=x^4y^2+x^2y^4-3x^2y^2+1$) is a counterexample, but I am still wondering what the intuition is on why the claim fails for non-negative polynomials.

**Edit** Actually the above is not a counterexample as that is not a homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: Isn't it because a representation like that implies the zero set of $p$ must be an intersection of hyperplanes if containing more than $0$? (Since the polynomial is homogenous it always vanishes at the zero vector, so positive here should mean $p(x_1,x_2,..x_n) > 0$ if $(x_1,..x_n)$ is not the zero vector); I would look at a simple example like $(x^2-y^2)^2$ which is non-negative but has two lines as its zero locus, so it can't be the intersection of planes passing through the origin